# Should I use the XSLTListViewWebpart (Alternative3) or go with Alternative 1 or 2

Tags: content-query-web-part, development

Say I have the following site hierarchy:

```
-Home
  - All Projects
    - Project123
    - Project456
    - Project789
    - ...
```

At the "All Project" site I need to show a list of all projects including the project state (on track or not). The list must be sortable and filterable.

Question is: How should I implement this?

My initial thought was the following:

- Have one list in every project named "ProjectStatus" with one entry with the current status
- Alt1) Use the content query web part at the "AllProject" to get the list (usure how to get the project name)
- Alt2) Create a web part that iterates through all subsites, and outputs a list of required info. (unsure of how to get paging and sorting)
- Alt3) Have a list at the "AllProject" that is constantly updated with eventreceivers on WebCreated (for new projects) and ItemChanged (for status changes). In this case I might use the XSLTListView

Any suggestions to how to implement this?

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to have a custom list at the All Projects level which keeps a track of all the subsites when they get created or deleted. Then use a CQWP to quer5 the same and use use the desired XSLT to display this information.